# Change output in a VBA from Activesheet to a new document (file)

Tags: vba, excel, output

I have excel-file (VBA) where i want the output in a separate file but i struggle to make it append.
The output should be everything below row6 in the worksheet.

```
Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
RST.Open SQL, mCON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

Do Until RST.EOF = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Getting data to row: " & lRow

    For n = 0 To (RST.Fields.Count - 1)
        If Not IsNull(RST(n)) Then ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, n + 1) = RST(n)

    Next

    RST.MoveNext
    lRow = lRow + 1
Loop

ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new workbook :

```
Dim wB As Excel.Workbook

Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
RST.Open Sql, mCON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
Set wB = Workbooks.Add
lRow = 6

Do Until RST.EOF = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Getting data to row: " & lRow

    For n = 0 To (RST.Fields.Count - 1)
        If Not IsNull(RST(n)) Then wB.Sheets(1).Cells(lRow, n + 1) = RST(n)
    Next n
    RST.MoveNext
    lRow = lRow + 1
Loop

wB.Sheets(1).Range("B5").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
```